# Null pointer when try to make a screenshot in testNG Selenium

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

When I try to do screen shots I get following error:

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.volvo.prompt.uitests.selenium.util.ScreenshotOnFailureListener.onConfigurationFailure(ScreenshotOnFailureListener.java:51)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runConfigurationListeners(Invoker.java:1868)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleConfigurationFailure(Invoker.java:334)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:237)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:101)
    ... 9 more
```

Here is the code: (51st line cause problems)

```
public class ScreenshotOnFailureListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {

        File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)TestBase.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String fileName = DateFormatter.getTimestamp(Calendar.getInstance()) + "."
                + System.getProperty("browser") + "."
                + tr.getMethod().getMethodName() 
                + ".png";
        String path = System.getProperty("webdriver.screenshots");
        File targetFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);

        if ( !targetFile.getParentFile().exists() ) {
            targetFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, targetFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Reporter.log("<a href=\"..\\..\\" + targetFile.getPath() + "\">Failed Screenshot</a>");
    }
```

Tests are run from Jenkins. Locally it works :/

Browser used: Chrome.

Thank You for replay in advance

BR
Jakub

Comment: `NullPointerException`...so something is null when it's running on Jenkins. Whatever is on line 51.

Comment: Seems like System properties are not set on jenkins e.g. "browser or "webdriver.screenshots". please check you have these properties configured on jenkins otherwise it will be null as per my understanding.